# python- Write in new PDF file using PyPDF2 .

Tags: python, python-2.7, pypdf

Suppose I want to write below lines in a new pdf file.

```
sdfdf = 123
ffwfwe = 456
fefwg = 34%
```

how am I suppose to do that? can you help?

I tried to do it using PdfFileReader class. Can we do that using it? 
If we use PdfFilewriter class, then does anyone know the use of write() function in it?

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_obj = open('result.pdf','w')
writer=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
writer.write("sdfdf = 123")
```

I'm just beginner in this module. So please bear with me. And couldn't find any help from the online documentation.

Comment: You should look at weasyprint. PyPDF2 is more suited for reading and merging pdf files.